# AS3 - Dispatch Event "change" for ComboBox

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm using the combobox component and I want to manually dispatch the "change" event. How is this done?

```
// Dispatches when user changes selection
comboType.addEventListener("change",cbListenerDialogue);

// Does not manually dispatch
comboType.dispatchEvent("change"); 
comboType.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string value you use for the dispatch has to match what's already defined in Flash.

This should to the trick.

`comboType.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE, true));`

Also: [AS3 Textbox Change Event Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977847/as3-textbox-change-event-not-firing)

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear,

```
comboType.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE, true));
```

works because bubbling is set to "true".

For example,

```
comboType.addEventListener("change",cbListenerDialogue);
comboType.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", true));
```

would work too. The important thing is that non mouse events won't propagate (bubble) unless set to true as Event.CHANGE and "change" are the same thing.